# Using web.config transformations in VS2013 with Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, config, azure-configuration

I am trying to have my production configuration settings within my web.Release.config file used when I publish my application to Microsoft Azure.

My scenario, is that I am using VS2013 and trying to publish to a production Cloud Service, running Azure.

I have read and followed many (now outdated) blog posts and SO questions/answers where the Whatever.Azure.ccproj is manually edited for VS2012/VS2010 and hand-stitched back together again, but none have worked for me.

Many of the steps that are suggested by these existing elements suggest creating versions of files that already exist in my project, and talk about creating Base files to depend upon.

Do I still need to do this in VS2013?  The IDE suggests to me that there's an easier way, but the direct information from Microsoft is hard to come by.

Many thanks, in advance.

Comment: my recommendation would be to set your configuration settings in the portal on azure.  If you have a setting with the same key in your web.config and in the settings on the portal, the portal settings will take effect on azure, ignoring the web.config value.  This has the added benefit of not having your production configuration settings exposed to all your developers.

Comment: That's quite interesting - hadn't thought of that.  Out of curiosity (and sheer laziness!!), am I able to do that with Identity keys (for Azure Active Directory) and SSL Certificate thumbprints too?

Comment: If you have a lot of deployment-slot specific settings, managing them in the Azure interface is a pain. How can I create a web.config file for each deployment slot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to move the settings from the web.config to the `ServiceConfiguration.*.cscfg` (e.g. Cloud, Local) then you are able to add additional versions of these files, such as `ServiceConfiguration.Staging.cscfg`.

During deployment (both via the IDE and via Powershell) you can specify which configuration to deploy.

In my case, I use `ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg` for the Production slot, and `ServiceConfiguration.Staging.cscfg` for the Staging slot.